# Digitally signing a pdf using only security certificate and pkcs7 file (no private key)

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

Can i digitally sign a pdf with a certifate (.cer) and .p7b certificates provided to me over a USB or do i need a private key to be provided as well. I have tried converting to various formats including .pem, .der, .key, .crt etc but end up with some exception or the other. Have tried converting to .pem and then .key and got 'no certificate matches private key'.

I want to know if i have incomplete information, or if i can use the available certificates and if yes how should i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need a private key to create a digital signature.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to some source where more information would be provided on this?

Comment: @Anonymous You can start at wikipedia with [Digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) and [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) topics.